# Using spring dependency management can't resolve dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

Hello I'm having problem to resolve dependencies when using spring dependency management plugin

I have a gradle project with subprojects and I'm using this config.

**build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version '1.0.11.RELEASE' 
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
}

apply from: './main.gradle'
```

**main.gradle file**

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "jacoco"
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
        
        implementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-core'
        implementation 'io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra'

        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    }


    jacoco {
        toolVersion = '0.8.2'
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to load some dependencies for every subproject in my project, like io.projectreactor:reactor-core

When I run a gradle refresh, I'm getting this message (for every subproject) on my intellij IDE console:

```
Could not resolve: org.projectlombok:lombok
Could not resolve: io.projectreactor:reactor-core
Could not resolve: io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra
Could not resolve: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test
Could not resolve: io.projectreactor:reactor-test
```

If I put versions explicit inside dependecies block then gradle resolve without problem but I don't want that

Any ideas about this issue ? How could I validate it ?

Gradle Wrapper Version: 6.8.3 (intellij is configured to use default gradle wrapper)

Thanks for your help

Regards!

Comment: You also need the Spring Boot Plugin else the versions won't get resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue, as @m-deinum suggets, I was missing spring-boot-gradle-plugin on dependencies at root project.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add 'org.springframework.boot' to the `plugins` section of every submodule's `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
}
```

You don't need to specify version in this case because it's already specified in the root `build.gradle`

Comment: hi @amseager I've added `apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'` inside subprojects block  in main.gradle file and that solved that messages when doing a gradle refresh. But now I have another issue, when running gradle build one subproject (domain-usecase) it can't find clases in another subproject (domain-model). I'm getting error: package does not exist. even though I have `dependencies {
    implementation project(':domain-model')
}` on project domain-usecase